# TFO Option number?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am to write a dissector for TFO in wireshark and was wondering what was the option number for this? I am not able to find this anywhere online

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cheng-tcpm-fastopen-02

Regards,

Vinay Pai B.H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not standardized yet. In Linux it is using `TCPOPT_EXP` which is `254`, followed by `TCPOPT_FASTOPEN_MAGIC` which is `0xF989`.

This adheres to [`RFC 6994`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6994) which outlines a scheme for experimental options.